# Periodically source shell profile

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, bashrc, .bash-profile

I'm a zsh user, but this should apply to any shell in theory. When I edit my `.zshrc` to add a new alias, I have to `source ~/.zshrc` in all of my open terminal tabs/windows to be able to use the new alias. I'm wondering if there's some way to have my open shells periodically source my profile automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The most complex and most real-time solution is to write a user trap function in `.zshrc` which when the trapped signal is caught, sources `.zshrc` itself.

Like this:

```
~$ cat .zshrc

trap includerc USR1

includerc() {
   source $HOME/.zshrc
}


alias xxx='df'
```

Within zsh, this can be seen now:

```
zshsession> alias
which-command=whence
xxx=df
```

Now some change in .zshrc

```
~$ cat .zshrc

trap includerc USR1

includerc() {
   source $HOME/.zshrc
}


alias xxx='df -g'
alias yyy='someothercommand'
```

Here comes the tricky part. Using `inotify` watching `.zshrc` or by a watcher script that examines the last modification of `.zshrc` a command is triggered that sends USR1 signal to all `zsh` processes of the user. Now I just ran it in another shell:

```
~$ ps -a | awk '$4=="zsh" {print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGUSR1
```

And the result is:

```
zshsession> alias
which-command=whence
xxx='df -g'
yyy=someothercommand
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. However, I'd rather use `killall -s USR1 zsh` than this ps-awk-xargs construct.

Comment: Valid correction. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

How about aliasing the command you use regularly?

You may need to adapt this for zsh:

```
myvi() {
    
    vi $1 
    source ~/.zshrc
}

alias vi=myvi
```

So when you `vi` anything, it will source `~/.zshrc`

You could do this with cd or ls for example.

## update

Another option would be to build it into your prompt:

```
export PS1="\$(source ~\.zshrc)\u@\h:\w\$"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've already built it into the command I use to edit my profile, but that only helps with the shell that I edited it from. Building it into my prompt seems more promising... Have you tried that?

Comment: @swrobel No, I haven't tried it specifically, but it should work fine - you must escape the first `$` otherwise it only runs the first time

Comment: Hmm, the `export` results in the following error and no prompt: `/Users/swrobel/.zshrc:export:8: not valid in this context: ~.zshrc}u@h:w$
zsh: bad substitution`

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typos. @swrobel

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutly right, this function might be constructed in any shell, and so since more than a quarter of century.

It is not, and from my point of vue here is why. Such a function could lead to a fatal termination of all shells running in case of a slightest error. Example: you have a code section for debugging which contains

```
exit 0
```

and during editing session of your `.zshrc` you removed the code protecting this exit to make it the general rule.
All your running `zsh` will end.
You won't be able to start another one with the same userid to fix your `.zshrc`.
You will have to use another account which is `sudo` enabled to fix the
killer `.zshrc`.

Then the best practice is to always test a `.zshrc` in a newly created shell so as to be able to survive.

This *missing* function is a very wise one.